# Understanding how to implement lodash's _.flowRight in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, closures, lodash

In school we have tasked to build an implementation of the [lodash method flowRight!](https://lodash.com/docs#flowRight)

In the spec it mentions:

> Takes an arbitrary amount of functions and returns a new function that
>   uses its arguments and calls the provided functions from right to left
>   (last to first). The argument for each function (except the first) is
>   determined by the return value of the function to its right. The call
>   to the function returned by flowRight evaluates to the return value of
>   the left most function.

And this is an example they give:

```
e.g.

var sayHello = function (name) {
    return 'Hello, ' + name;
},

addExclamation = function (s) {
    return s + '!';
},

smallTalk = function (s) {
    return s + ' Nice weather we are having, eh?';
};

var greetEnthusiastically = flowRight(addExclamation, sayHello);

greetEnthusiastically('Antonio');
// --> returns 'Hello, Antonio!'
//(sayHello is called with 'Antonio', 
//  addExclamation is called with 'Hello, Antonio')
```

I feel like I understand what is going on in a static example like this example demostrates.

```
function (func1, func2) {
    return function(value) {
        return func1(func2(value));
    }
}
```

Guess I am having a hard time wrapping my brain around doing it in a loop, which I think you'll need. This is my implementation so far.

```
var flowRight = function (...args) {
    var Func;
    for(var i = args.length - 2; 0 > i; i--) {
        function Func(value) {
            return args[i](args[i + 1](value));
        }
    }
    return Func;
};
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need for a loop. This uses ES6 if that is permitted.

This uses [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), [`rest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
const flowRight = (...functions) => functions.reduce((a, c) => (...args) => a(c(...args)));
```

Example below

```js
var sayHello = function (name) {
  return 'Hello, ' + name;
 },

addExclamation = function (s) {
  return s + '!';
},

smallTalk = function (s) {
  return s + ' Nice weather we are having, eh?';
}

const flowRight = (...functions) => functions.reduce((a, c) => (...args) => a(c(...args)))

var greetEnthusiastically = flowRight(smallTalk, addExclamation, sayHello)

console.log(greetEnthusiastically('Antonio'));
```

Comment: `reduceRight` simplifies things as it doesn't need the intermediary `(...args) =>`

Answer (score 5):

To flow from right to left you can use the [`...spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) with [`.reduceRight(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

I've commented the code below to try and explain how this all works together.

```js
const sayHello = function (name) {
  return 'Hello, ' + name;
 };

const addExclamation = function (s) {
  return s + '!';
};

const smallTalk = function (s) {
  return s + ' Nice weather we are having, eh?';
}

// function that takes functions and then
// returns a function that takes  a value to apply to those functions in reverse
const flowRight = (...fns) => val => fns.reduceRight((val, fn) => {
  // return the function and pass in the seed value or the value of the pervious fn.
  // You can think of it like the following.
  // 1st pass: sayHello(value) -> "Hello, " + value;
  // 2nd pass: addExclamation("Hello,  $value") -> "Hello,  $value" + "!";
  // 3rd pass: smallTalk("Hello,  $value!") -> "Hello,  $value!" + ' Nice weather we are having, eh?'
  // ... and so on, the reducer will keep calling the next fn with the previously returned value
  return fn(val)
// seed the reducer with the value passed in
}, val);

var greetEnthusiastically = flowRight(smallTalk, addExclamation, sayHello);

console.log(greetEnthusiastically('Antonio'));
```

Answer (score 2):

**right-to-left composition**

```js
const flowRight = (f, ...more) => x =>
  f == null ? x : f(flowRight(...more)(x))

const upper = s =>
  s.toUpperCase()

const greeting = s =>
  `Hello, ${s}`

const addQuotes = s =>
  `"${s}"`

const sayHello =
  flowRight(addQuotes, greeting, upper)

console.log(sayHello("world"))
// "Hello, WORLD"
```

**left-to-right composition**

```js
const flowLeft = (f, ...more) => x =>
  f == null ? x : flowLeft(...more)(f(x))

const upper = s =>
  s.toUpperCase()

const greeting = s =>
  `Hello, ${s}`

const addQuotes = s =>
  `"${s}"`

const sayHello =
  flowLeft(addQuotes, greeting, upper)

console.log(sayHello("world"))
// HELLO, "WORLD"
```

---

**using reduceRight**

We can use `reduceRight` to easily implement `flowRight` -

```js
const flowRight = (...fs) => init =>
  fs.reduceRight((x, f) => f(x), init)

const upper = s =>
  s.toUpperCase()

const greeting = s =>
  `Hello, ${s}`

const addQuotes = s =>
  `"${s}"`

const sayHello =
  flowRight(addQuotes, greeting, upper)

console.log(sayHello("world"))
// "Hello, WORLD"
```

**using reduce**

Or we can use `reduce` to easily implement `flowRight` -

```js
const flowLeft = (...fs) => init =>
  fs.reduce((x, f) => f(x), init)

const upper = s =>
  s.toUpperCase()

const greeting = s =>
  `Hello, ${s}`

const addQuotes = s =>
  `"${s}"`

const sayHello =
  flowLeft(addQuotes, greeting, upper)

console.log(sayHello("world"))
// HELLO, "WORLD"
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea in the function written below is to return a function that will iterate over the list of functions and store result from each call and return it at the end.

```
function flowRight(...args) {
    return function (initial) {
        let value = initial;

        for (let i = args.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            value = args[i](value);
        }

        return value;   
    };
}
```